# como buscar en tabla php con jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

Buenas, estoy intentando realizar una búsqueda en una tabla php.

Este es el codigo con el cual muestro mi tabla:

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="search">Buscar:</label>
              <div class="input-group col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" REQUIRED class="form-control"  id="search" placeholder="Ingresar Nombre">

              </div>
          </div>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                      <thead>
                        <tr bgcolor="#AFDDEC">

                    <th>Cliente</th>
                    <th>Tipo Documento</th>
                    <th>Documento</th>
                    <th>Direccion</th>

                        </tr>

                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      <?php 
                        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

                          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                        echo '<tr><td>'.$row["nombre"].' '.$row["apellidos"].
                        '</td><td>'.$row["tipo_doc"].
                        '</td><td>'.$row["dni"].
                        '</td><td>'.$row["direccion"].
                        '</td></tr>';

                          }
                      } else {
                          echo "0 results";
                      }
                    ?>
                      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Y aqui el fragmento de jquery, con el cual pensaba que podía implementarlo:

```
var $rows = $('.table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

Pero el código simplemente no hace nada. Alguna sugerencia para poder buscar en mi tabla? Perdonen las molestias pero soy nuevo en esto. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por que no intentas usar [Jquery datatables](https://datatables.net/), es una libreria muy buena, y te ahorra mucho trabajo. Es solo una sugerencia

Comment: ¿has comprobado si salen errores de Javascript? al menos mete una sentencia `console.log` con la variable `val` para comprobar que se está ejecutando la función en cada pulsación del teclado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrias hacer uso de la libreria

[quickSearch](https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch)

con esta libreria podrias realizas busquedas en una tabla html directo en el cliente sobre los datos que se listan

```js
$(function () {

  $('#search').quicksearch('table tbody tr');        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.quicksearch/2.2.1/jquery.quicksearch.js"></script>


<div class="row large-centered">
        
    </div>
    <div class="row large-centered">
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Escribe para buscar..." />
        <table id="table" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre Personaje</th>
                    <th>Clase</th>
                    <th>Reino</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Benjamin.</td>
                <td>Rogue.</td>
                <td>Uldum ES.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cachoito.</td>
                <td>Hunter.</td>
                <td>Agamaggan EN.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Contemplario.</td>
                <td>Paladin.</td>
                <td>Uldum ES.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Elthron.</td>
                <td>Death Knight.</td>
                <td>Agamaggan ES.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Giloh.</td>
                <td>Priest.</td>
                <td>Agamaggan EN.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Kitialamok.</td>
                <td>Warrior.</td>
                <td>Agamaggan EN.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Magustroll.</td>
                <td>Mage.</td>
                <td>Agamaggan EN.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Marselus.</td>
                <td>Mage.</td>
                <td>Uldum ES.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mistrala.</td>
                <td>Warrior.</td>
                <td>Uldum ES.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suavemente.</td>
                <td>Warrior.</td>
                <td>Agamaggan EN.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tittus.</td>
                <td>Monk.</td>
                <td>Agamaggan EN.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yarlokk.</td>
                <td>Warlock.</td>
                <td>Uldum ES.</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Te comparto una solucion que existe en SO en Inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567426/search-html-table-with-js-and-jquery

Aunque mejor es implementar una herramienta como **[jquery datatables](https://datatables.net/)** que te facilita toda esta tarea.

```js
    // captura el evento keyup cuando escribes en el input
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        _this = this;
        // Muestra los tr que concuerdan con la busqueda, y oculta los demás.
        $.each($("#table tbody tr"), function() {
            if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
               $(this).hide();
            else
               $(this).show();                
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row large-centered">
        
    </div>
    <div class="row large-centered">
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Escribe para buscar..." />
        <table id="table" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre Personaje</th>
                    <th>Clase</th>
                    <th>Reino</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Benjamin.</td>
                <td>Rogue.</td>
                <td>Uldum ES.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cachoito.</td>
                <td>Hunter.</td>
                <td>Agamaggan EN.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Contemplario.</td>
                <td>Paladin.</td>
                <td>Uldum ES.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Elthron.</td>
                <td>Death Knight.</td>
                <td>Agamaggan ES.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Giloh.</td>
                <td>Priest.</td>
                <td>Agamaggan EN.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Kitialamok.</td>
                <td>Warrior.</td>
                <td>Agamaggan EN.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Magustroll.</td>
                <td>Mage.</td>
                <td>Agamaggan EN.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Marselus.</td>
                <td>Mage.</td>
                <td>Uldum ES.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mistrala.</td>
                <td>Warrior.</td>
                <td>Uldum ES.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suavemente.</td>
                <td>Warrior.</td>
                <td>Agamaggan EN.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tittus.</td>
                <td>Monk.</td>
                <td>Agamaggan EN.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yarlokk.</td>
                <td>Warlock.</td>
                <td>Uldum ES.</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```